# Should all elements have unique class name in a native Android application?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I used UI automation viewer to get an xpath selector for class and Appium driver states (correctly) that:
*** Capybara::Ambiguous Exception: Ambiguous match, found 4 elements matching visible xpath "//android.widget.Button"

Elements have different `text` property, so I could identify by this property, however I imagine things would get complicated in case the app  has multiple languages available.

The article below seems to hint that because elements can share class names, locating by class only is not recommended:
https://seleniumbycharan.com/2016/08/07/finding-elements-using-locators-in-appium/

One solution would be to form an array of these elements and simply refer to an index. 
Another is to use the text property.
I do not like either of these solutions.

Should I recommend the developer to assign some IDs or just varied class names, or are identical class name chains common in native app dev and this is not an anti-pattern in any way?

Comment: Using different classes for like elements would be an anti-pattern. A class defines the behaviour of the element. This is quite different from the class in HTML/CSS which is mainly used to define the presentation.

Comment: I would need a screenshot or something of the element you're trying to click to be able to really answer this but yea what henry said using different classes for elements would be an anti pattern and locating elements by class is just a bad idea in general since there are tons of elements that are the same class name by default.

Answer (score 2):

When I launched the app in Appium Inspector, it said: 
"Using XPath locators is not recommended and can lead to fragile tests. Ask your development team to provide unique accessibility locators instead!"
Ideally, it should instead autogenerate a short and unique selector.

For Android, either `resource-id` or `content-desc` should not be empty and if possible should contain unique values.

For iOS, it's `accessibility-id` or `name`.

Based on: http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/

Answer (score -1):

Ya, but as you can see i have nothing else than XPATH.