# Selenium/Java - Unclickable XPATH

Tags: java, selenium, testing, xpath, appium

I have application to automate and there is a XPATH which is not clickable in the automated test. Appium says it's visible and clickable but test run says: nope.

I have tried but it doesn't work:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//android.view.View[@content-desc=\"Benachrichtigung WIll's Haus Entfernung 0 km Deine Reichweite 0.0 km Zu gehen 0.0 km\"]/android.widget.ImageView[18]")
    public WebElement clickIt;
```

Is there any other way to click it?

[Appium SShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PByGC.png)

Comment: Are you getting an error, or just not seeing the click action you expect?

Comment: what element is it ?

Answer (score -1):

You received a warning that explains exactly:

> Using XPath locators is not recommended and can lead to fragile tests. Ask your development team to provide unique accessibility locators instead!

See similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479105/should-all-elements-have-unique-class-name-in-a-native-android-application).

Comment: The problem isn't with xpath... it's with BAD xpath..

Comment: Using an index position in xpath is a bad idea. It is still valid xpath syntax and will work fine on any xpath engine, but may be a risk in the future. When someone adds new element at the beginning of xml, xpath will return wrong value.

Comment: That's bad xpath. Misusing a tool doesn't make the whole tool bad. Flaky selectors are flaky in any method (css, xpath...)